# Zabbix agent daemon does not pickup a PID

Tags: command-line, launchd, plist

[(I've searched similar cases and could not find any)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440277/disable-enable-launchd-daemon-agents)

I've installed Zabbix agent daemon for MacOS. I'm running it on Catalina.

The daemon ran just fine on installation, however after a while it crashed and then I cannot revive it even with a reboot.

If I try to search the daemon with `sh-3.2# ps auxc | grep -i zabbix` it's not there.

I go to launchctl and find this:

```
sh-3.2# launchctl list | grep -i zabbix
-   1   com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd
```

I try to start it with `launchctl start com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd` but no luck.
I tried:

```
# launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd.plist 
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd.plist: service already loaded
```

But then I run launchctl list and nothing.

If I debug it, I get:

```
# launchctl debug gui/501/com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd
Configuration failed: 113: Could not find specified service
Could not find service "com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd" in domain for login: 100006
```

But I'm at loss what this could mean. If I check the daemon, there's no owner errors or anything:

```
 $ ls -hal /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   775B Feb 26 09:31 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.zabbix.zabbix_agentd.plist
```

Any leads or pointers?

Comment: Please don’t post “ I’ve searched for things” without being explicit what you searched. It is considered chit chat and doesn’t help us help you. Sharing your research is encouraged, but you have to share details for it to be effective.

Comment: Hello @bmike! I'm not sure how does my comment makes my question less clear. Please at least provide a reason why it makes it less clear before deliberately editing someone else's post. Thank you so much for your contribution!

Comment: @bmike, added link to my research on my statement to make it more effective.

Comment: What is the content of the plist? Is there anything of interest in the logs?

Comment: Hello @nohillside! I think you gave me a MASSIVE lead here. plist shows `<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
 <string>/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd-err.log</string>
 <key>StandardOutPath</key>
 <string>/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd-out.log</string>` looking at that error log I see `zabbix_agentd [2830]: ERROR: StartAgents is not 0, parameter "Server" must be defined` I guess that's where I need to start digging... Thank you!!

Comment: Yep, that fixed it, it was a commented line. Thank you @nohillside! Can you make your comment an answer so I can resolve my question? Thanks again!

Comment: I just pointed out a few places to look at. Feel free to self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @nohillside managed to dig deeper into plist file for the agent and found this:

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd-err.log</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd-out.log</string>
```

looking at that error log file, I see `zabbix_agentd [2830]: ERROR: StartAgents is not 0, parameter "Server" must be defined`

I added the "Server" option and it worked just fine.